# How to print many spaces and then print word on the same line in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to print word with some spaces on the start of line, and I need to set spaces count with variable.

This code is not working:

```
spaces=20

echo "spaces: $spaces"

for ((n=0;n<$spaces;n++))
do
    printf '%s' ''
done
    
printf '%s' 'hello!'
```

Real output:

```
spaces: 20

hello!
```

Expected output:

```
spaces: 20
    
                    hello!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use single `printf` to get desired number of padding of spaces:

```
printf '%*s\n' "$spaces" 'hello!'
```

```
               hello!
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
    printf '%s' ''
```

To this:

```
    printf '%s' ' '
```

Or even this:

```
    printf ' '
```

Or just replace **the whole program** with:

```
s=20; printf %$s's\n' "hello!"
```

Comment: Nice job explaining how to expand the OP's attempt to make it work _and_ **also** giving a more elegant solution. What's even better is that you give an elegant solution, ( `s=20; printf %$s's\n' "hello!"` ), which was different than the [accepted, elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683956/6505499) ( `printf '%*s\n' "$spaces" 'hello!'` ) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20240214184935/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683894/how-to-print-many-spaces-and-then-print-word-on-the-same-line-in-bash))  +1